# Filter an array based on data from two different arrays using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to filter an array based on the data of the two different arrays. Below is the example and expected result.

```
let groupedProtocolFilterValues = [
    ["Risk score < 4"]
];
let groupedPatientFilterValues = [
    ["CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM", "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM"]
];

let events = [{
    "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e5",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Risk score < 3",
        "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
    "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e6",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Risk score < 4",
        "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
    "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e7",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Risk score < 4",
        "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
    "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e8",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Risk score < 4",
        "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}];
```

Here i would like to filter 'event' array based on the data of 'groupedProtocolFilterValues' and 'groupedPatientFilterValues'. So looking at the current data expected result should be

```
events = [{
    "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e6",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Risk score < 4",
        "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
    "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e7",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Risk score < 4",
        "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}];
```

I want to check if any of the "events" array element contains "Risk score < 4" and "CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM" or "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM".

In short i need to apply below filtration condition:

ANDING BETWEEN 'groupedPatientFilterValues/groupedProtocolFilterValues'

ORING WITHIN 'groupedPatientFilterValues' AND 'groupedProtocolFilterValue'

Comment: Is it possible to change the structure of `groupedPatientFilterValues` array? It would be much easier to work with array of string rather then with array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not needed to use lodash for this task, `.filter` will do the work:

```js
let groupedProtocolFilterValues = [
  ["Risk score < 4"]
];
let groupedPatientFilterValues = [
  ["CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM", "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM"]
];

let flattenedProtocols = groupedProtocolFilterValues.reduce((res, cur) => res = res.concat(cur), []);
let flattenedLocations = groupedPatientFilterValues.reduce((res, cur) => res = res.concat(cur), []);

let events = [{
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e5",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 3",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e6",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 4",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e7",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 4",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e8",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 4",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}];

const result = events.filter(x => {
  return (!flattenedProtocols.length || flattenedProtocols.indexOf(x.alert.title) >= 0) &&
    (!flattenedLocations.length || flattenedLocations.some(c => x.alert.patientLocation.includes(c)));
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that if i pass groupedPatientFilterValues  as an empty array, i.e. groupedPatientFilterValues  = [[]] , i should get last three elements of array 'events' as a result since 'groupedProtocolFilterValues' value is "Risk score < 4".

Comment: It can be fixed by adding an additional check. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: If future if i add one more filter condition in `groupedPatientFilterValues = [
 ["CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM", "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM"],
 ["LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME"]` suppose for name which i want to check against events.alert.name. What will be the changes i need to do.
]

Comment: It depends on your logic. With my approach all values inside `groupedPatientFilterValues` arrays are combined in single array and treated equally. So for your example events will be selected if event's `patientLocation` contains one of next values: `CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM`, `CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM`, `LAST_NAME`, `FIRST_NAME`. But if next pair of conditions should use some other logic then code muse be changed and only you can know how.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lodash, use `filter` .

```js
let groupedProtocolFilterValues = [
  ["Risk score < 4"]
];
let groupedPatientFilterValues = [
  ["CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM", "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM"]
];

let events = [{
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e5",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 3",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e6",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 4",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e7",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 4",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY CHF INTERN2 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}, {
  "_id": "5d087b842c3f77e7a0c674e8",
  "alert": {
    "title": "Risk score < 4",
    "patientLocation": "CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM\r\r\nCARDIOMYOPATHY CONSULT"
  },
  "createdAt": "2019-06-18T05:49:56.402Z"
}];

const output = events.filter(({
  alert: {
    title,
    patientLocation
  }
}) => {
  return groupedProtocolFilterValues[0].includes(title) && groupedPatientFilterValues[0].some((val) => {
    const patientLocationName = patientLocation.split('\n')[0];
    return val.trim().includes(patientLocationName.trim());
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that if i pass groupedPatientFilterValues as an empty array, i.e. groupedPatientFilterValues = [[]] , i should get last three elements of array 'events' as a result since 'groupedProtocolFilterValues' value is "Risk score < 4". Similar scenario is also for groupedProtocolFilterValues when it is empty.